# Prevent NSURLSession from caching responses

Tags: swift, caching, nsurlsession, nsurlcache, nsurlsessionconfiguration

Why does it cache responses. It returns previously fetched responses. It even works if turning off the network connection. Resetting the iOS simulator did not seem to work either. Making a request, then again with internet offline does work (cached).

```
public let urlSession: NSURLSession

public init()
{
    // ...

    var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
}

func makeRequest(path: String, httpMethod:String, body:String?, baseUrl: String?, headers:[String:String]=[:], callback: JsonRequestCallback)
{
    let urlString = (baseUrl ?? customOAuth2Manager.API_URL) + path
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let request = oauthInstance.request(forURL: url!)

    request.HTTPMethod = httpMethod
    self.customOAuth2Manager.setupRequest(request)

    for (key, value) in headers {
        request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField:key)
    }

    if let body = body where body != "" {
        let postData = (body as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        request.HTTPBody = postData
    }

    let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        self.parseData(data, response:response, error:error, body:body, callback: callback)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**Update**

I managed to solve it by calling this code from `didFinishLaunching` in the `AppDelegate`:

```
func removeUrlCache()
{
    NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil))
}
```

However, I'm still curious why my original code does not work. It also feels a bit ugly to disable cache for all the app to solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks!! Did you discover more about this?

Comment: add `configuration.URLCache` to `nil` when you are creating `NSURLSessionConfiguration` object and responses will not be cached.

Answer (score 21):

Thanks for the question. It put me on the right path.

There are more possibilities with `NSURLCache.sharedURLCache()` and you don't need to change the memory capacity and disk capacity for this.

You can remove all cached responses. **Works for me.**

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Or you can remove the cache for a single response. **Not working for me iOS 9.**

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
    URLCache.shared.removeCachedResponse(for: request)

//Do your request here
```

I hope it helps someone out!

**Edit:**
`NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeCachedResponseForRequest(request)` is not working for me unfortunately

My alternative was: I'm using this for pull to refresh and i'm tracking the last update date. So I was using the following code:

```
 URLCache.shared.removeCachedResponses(since: lateUpdate)
```

But for some reason this is not working ether.

Since iOS 8, single cache remove methods seems to be broken: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26343653/2826164

2019-05-24, updated to Swift 5.

Comment: I used an alternative for removing a cached response for a specific request, reseting the cached response, see my answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/36507745/1080583

Comment: Do you know whether it works for simulator differently than for actual device? I used this approach, and on simulator even removing all cache on call to `applicationWillResignActive` still leaves full Cache.db file.

Comment: I've tested this on device only. You can try to clean xCode cache maybe this will give a different result in de simulator (to clean xCode cache cmd+alt+shift+K)

Comment: I know you have your answer that works, but would it work to use the  ephemeral-session instead?https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1410529-ephemeral

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if this actually prevents from chaching or just forces a fresh reload every time, but this is what worked for me:

```
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
```

Here's a screenshot showing other options in case someone may need them:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would implement URLSessionDelegate and call the completionBlock with nil in the willCache delegate implementation. This was your requests will never be chached

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**
Setting sessionConfig.URLCache = nil will disable caching.

```
/* The URL resource cache, or nil to indicate that no caching is to be performed */
@property (nullable, retain) NSURLCache *URLCache;
```

This is default to nil in **background sessions** so caching is disabled by default.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1410148-urlcache

**Option 2**

Implementing following delegate method and calling completionHandler(nil) will prevent caching.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
                                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)proposedResponse 
                                  completionHandler:(void (^)(NSCachedURLResponse * _Nullable cachedResponse))completionHandler
```

Note that this delegate method is called only for uploads and data tasks, and is not called for sessions with a background or ephemeral configuration.

Ref : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/accessing_cached_data

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 5, you just have to specify cache policy:

```
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
```